# Passing a string value(date) from an activity to another fragment's textview

Tags: java, android

I'm having null values from passing a string value which contains time&date from an activity to another fragment that carries the textview. Is there a method to carry these values into another one of my fragment's java class(Notifications.java)?

```
            date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
            date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

I got this error:

```
rogue.queue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: rogue.queue, PID: 20762
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at rogue.queue.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
```

Using the fab button to pass the value to another fragment:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Add a new queue", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Notifications()).commit();
            date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_notifications);
    }
});
```

Here's my Notifications java class for the fragment

```
public class Notifications extends Fragment {
TextView servingqueue;
TextView date;
String dateGET;

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mServingQueue = mRootRef.child("ServingQueue");


public Notifications() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle pb=getArguments();
    dateGET=pb.getString("date");


    mServingQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Double number = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
            servingqueue.setText(String.valueOf(number));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragmentid.queueServing);
    servingqueue = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.queueServing);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
//        date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    date.setText(dateGET);

    }
}
```

Here is my mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Home.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    //Read Firebase Database

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private TextView textViewUserEmail;
    private MenuItem nav_logout;
    TextView servingqueue;
TextView date;


FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Launches Home() fragment
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Home()).commit();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Add a new queue", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
//                Queue.getQueue();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Notifications()).commit();
//                date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
//         

   date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

            Fragment fragment2=new Notifications();
            Bundle arg= new Bundle();
            arg.putString("date","DATE");
            fragment2.setArguments(arg);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment2);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();

//                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment2).commit();

            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_notifications);
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();



    //User Profile Interface
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    View HeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    textViewUserEmail = (TextView) HeaderView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
    textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome "+user.getEmail());
//        nav_logout = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_logout);
//        nav_logout.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
     else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Home()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_notifications) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Notifications()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Settings()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent (this, Login.class));
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Scanner.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Here is the xml that i am editing:

Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="rogue.queue.Notifications"
android:id="@+id/notification_relative_layout">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:text="Your Number:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/myqueue"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Current Number:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myqueue"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/myqueue" />

<TextView
    android:text="PLEASE BE SEATED"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/queueServing"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/queueServing"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/myqueue" />

<TextView
    android:text="YOU WILL BE SERVED SHORTLY"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Welcome to Sunway Education Group"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textDate"
    tools:text="00 - JAN - 0000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9" />

<Button
    android:text="CANCEL QUEUE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonQueueCancel"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    />
```

Here is the app_main_bar of where the fab is located at linking to the mainactivity.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px" />
```

Comment: date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate); is null. textDate view is inside activity xml or fragment?

Comment: It's inside the other fragment

Comment: then u can't use this like you u did. you need to pass that value to fragment and fragment's onViewCreated method show that value in textview.

Comment: in your on click method, view.findViewById will definitely return null as `view` variable is the view that you just clicked. and it do not contain the viee you are searching for. replace view with `getView()` but do chrck that grtView() is not null

Answer (score 1):

I tested it in mydevice and it is working perfectly:

activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linn"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="maker.jsonp.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
String time= DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                Fragment fragment2=new Notifications();
                Bundle arg= new Bundle();
                arg.putString("date",time);
                fragment2.setArguments(arg);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now, fragment code:

```
public class Notifications extends Fragment {

    TextView servingqueue;
    TextView date;
    String dateGET;

    public Notifications() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle pb=getArguments();
        dateGET=pb.getString("date");

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragmentid.queueServing);
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        date.setText(dateGET);
    }

}
```

Comment: I got a null pointer exception `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at rogue.queue.Notifications.onViewCreated(Notifications.java:85)`

I inserted the `Bundle pb= getArguments()` etc onto my other fragment's onViewCreated method

Comment: no, put Bundle pb=getArguments();
        String dateGET=pb.getString("date");
in oncreate() of fragment.

Comment: That just gets me error for dateGet that is still on `onViewCreated`.When i place `Bundle pb=getArguments();
        String dateGET=pb.getString("date");

        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        date.setText(dateGET);` on `onCreate()` I get error on `view`

Comment: Post your whole code of fragment as well as activity code that replace fragment with click action.

Comment: Done. Edited to fit the solution you gave. Error lies in `        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);`

Comment: No. The problem lies in `date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);`where it cannot resolve symbol 'view'

Comment: Your fragment code is not valid, you move your textview code to OncreateView and change view to rootView

Comment: Okay i have moved  `dateGET=pb.getString("date"); date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);         date.setText(dateGET);` to onCreateView and rename it as        `date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);` but im trying to figure out the error i get on `        date.setText(dateGET);`

Comment: First of all. Never create view or populate data in view inside oncreate method of fragment.just put your bundle code inside oncreate. In OncreateView method just inflate Layout xml. All other findViewbyid and settext and listener should be in OnViewCreated method. Please look at fragment lifecycle

Comment: Okay so i've put back `date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        date.setText(dateGET);` to onCreate. The error as mentioned early is still there with `view` listed as "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Post your xml of fragment. I am implement in my app and gives you working code

Comment: Done. See title for xml of the fragment.

Comment: I will give you code after some time, i need to go somewhere.

Comment: I am busy now, i don't have laptop right now, but i solve your problem after 2-3 hour

Comment: I followed your code to the T. But i still get Nullpointer exception at `dateGET=pb.getString("date");` I have updated the title with the updated code.

Comment: Commrnt the fourth line(fragment transaction) of your fab onclick method and try again.

Comment: Remove date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())); from mainactivity

Comment: Change "DATE" to DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) in argument method.

Comment: I'm getting cannot resolve method getInstance() after making this change

`arg.putString("date",DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance‌​().getTime()) );`

Comment: use: String time= DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());     and arg.putString("date",time);

Comment: getTime displays cannot resolve method after inserting these two lines and removing the line before.

Comment: i am currently using:    String time= DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(time);

Comment: Removing the two lines and replace with the 3 lines you provided. I get cannot resolve symbol on tv from `TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);` and cannot resolve method on getTime() like previously on `                String time= DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().g‌​etTime());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127991/discussion-between-anonymous-vagrant-and-divyesh).